# Package textpos defining textblock in width of \textwidth and relative commands

Tags: textpos

I have some questions, that won't be solved by the documentation.

1.) [This is solved, solution in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP7eo.png)]I would like to do

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{\textwidth}(0,0)
Text of full paperwidth, doesn't matter, if i'd chose a4 to a0
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

but \textwidth doesn't work. My intention is: Defining a fixed block at fixed position of relative width, depending on the chosen paper-size. This leads to my 2nd question.

2.) Is there a way, to declare textblocks orientated on an anchor "top, right" instead of "top, left". Am I able to define anchors for textblock like: top=xx, right=xx. Or bottom=xx, left=xx?

3.) How to set a backgroundcolor to textbox?

4.) How to make the outer-text of textbox don't underlay the textbox? If I declare a Textbox as a heading-element, and inserting something outside of this, i'll achive the following image:
[image]
The blue bar shows the end of the textbox-environment. So if I do

```
\begin{textbox}
inner text
\end{textbox}
outer text
```

I would like to have the "outer text" just below the textbox, so that \clearpage and other commands will still work.

**Solution**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP7eo.png) Credits to Jürgen

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0cm,0cm)
    Text of full paperwidth, doesn't matter, if i'd chose a4 to a0
\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

[3] Credits to Documentation
Using the command below, defines the backgroundcolor of all Textboxes

```
\textblockcolour{hcolour i}
```

Credits to Jürgen for giving the hint to:

> fcolourbox
>   This will be another solution for just one box.

Comment: I would like to propose to separate the third aspect into a new question as it is not related to the textpos package.

Comment: ok. I'll do so and erase it from here.

Comment: To question 4)

I do not know if I understand you correctly, but this looks like you are searching for a floating object. Or something like `wrapfig`? I think you should show us what you want to achieve finally.

Comment: Ok. I'll Try. I'll add an image.

Comment: Then, I think, textpos is not the right package for you. It can not manage the flow of the text *outside* of the textblocks. You may look into the documentation if the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: hm.. it would be a solution, if I could get the height of the textbox. Then I would reduce the "textheight" by this height and setting up "\setlength{\headheight}{\textboxheight}"

Comment: `\headheight`? So you want to put the `\textblock` into the headline?

Answer (score 3):

To question 1)

If you like to use absolute values, then you have to use the starred version.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0cm,0cm)
Text of full paperwidth, doesn't matter, if i'd chose a4 to a0
\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

To question 2)

I think with internal means of this package this is not possible. But an idea: One might put the contents of the textblock into a box, measure its height and change the vertical position parameter of the textblock accordingly. Should work, but I am not sure whether this is the most elegant way ...

To question 3)

`\textblockcolor` is of course the canonical solution. [`\fcolorbox` is another solution which works independent of this package. It may lead to problems with the correct adjustment inside of textblocks.]

Comment: I would swear, I had tried exact this code and this didn't worked. As I used it right now, it works. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: your 2nd solution will probably work. I'll add a third question to this.

Comment: Question 3.) is, therefore, answered. I will add a solution from the documentation.

Comment: i've added one last question: How to disable the text, that is putted in outside the textbox, underlaying the textbox?